# v-model on textarea overwriting content

Tags: vue.js, v-model

Learning Vue, I'm iterating through an object and I want to be able to display some content in each textarea and identify the textarea individually for updating etc, but I have an issue as v-model fills it with the identifier number.

I tried to include the content directly in the textarea with {{}}, v-model overwrites it.

my code is pretty simple:

```
textarea.text(v-model="index")
    | {{content.value}}
```

I end up with my fields filled with just a number while I would want `content.value` for instance

Comment: It is kinda strange, that you use a variable "index" as a textarea model. Anyway: use the hook function "beforeMount", to overwrite "index" with the content of 'content.value'. See here for more info and the vue lifecycle diagram: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeMount

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<textarea   
    :value="textareaValue"
    @input="input($event.target.value)"
    @focus="onFocus"
    @blur="onBlur"
>
```

Where `input` is the method where you do something with the text when you write. and :value is the text which is displayed ( initial lets say).

You can wrap this inside your compoennt my-textarea.
Just be sure to emit the value inside your `input` method, and set `value` prop.

```
  <my-textarea
        v-model="parentValue"
></my-textarea>
```